# Solving the maze problem using recursion and backtracking

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to solve the maze problem using Java, the code works completely fine using only two directions (right and downwards), however, I want to make it search/move in all direction it throws an error (Stack overflow).

The code below:

```
  public class Maze {

    int n,m,startX,startY,endX,endY;

    public Maze(int n,int m) {
        this.n = n;
        this.m = m;
    }

    public void findLocation(int[][]array)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < array.length;i++)
            for(int j = 0 ; j <array[i].length;j++)
                {if(array[i][j] == 3)
                {
                    startX = i;
                    startY = j;
                }
                if(array[i][j] == 9)
                {
                    endX = i;
                    endY = j;
                }
                }
    }

    public boolean isSafe(int[][]array,int x, int y)
    {
        return (x>=0 && x < n && y>=0 && y<m && array[x][y]!=0);
    }

    public boolean solution(int[][] array)
    {
        int[][]sol = new int[n][m];

        findLocation(array);
        if(solutionUtil(array,startX,startY,sol)==false)
        {
            System.out.println("no solution");
            return false;
        }

        printsolution(sol);
        return true;
    }

private void printsolution(int[][] sol) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i=0; i < sol.length;i++)
    {   for(int j = 0 ; j <sol[i].length;j++)
             System.out.print(" " + sol[i][j] + 
                     " "); 
        System.out.println(); 
             }
    }

private boolean solutionUtil(int[][] array, int x, int y, int[][] sol) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(x == endX && y == endY)
        {
            sol[x][y] = 1;
            return true;
        }

        if(isSafe(array,x,y))
        {
            sol[x][y] = 1;

            if(x!=0)
            {
                if(solutionUtil(array,x-1,y,sol)==true)
                    return true;
            }
            if(y!=0)
            {
                if(solutionUtil(array,x,y-1,sol)==true)
                    return true;
            }

            if(solutionUtil(array,x+1,y,sol)==true)
                return true;
            if(solutionUtil(array,x,y+1,sol)==true)
                return true;

            sol[x][y] =0;
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int[][] array = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, 
            {1, 1, 3, 1}, 
            {0, 1, 0, 0}, 
            {1, 1, 1, 9}};

    Maze run = new Maze(4,4);
    run.solution(array);


}

}
```

The starting point is 3 and the ending point is 9, 1 means it can move, 0 means it can't move(barrier), how can I avoid the error, hence, the ability the traverse in all directions, what is wrong in my code?

Comment: What is the exact error thrown? And at what line in your code is it thrown?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: @ChrisGong it keep repeating this error between those lines 
   if(x!=0)
   {
    if(solutionUtil(array,x-1,y,sol)==true)
     return true;
   }
   if(y!=0)
   {
    if(solutionUtil(array,x,y-1,sol)==true)
     return true;
   }
   
   if(solutionUtil(array,x+1,y,sol)==true)
    return true;
   if(solutionUtil(array,x,y+1,sol)==true)
    return true;

Comment: I'd guess it's moving back and forwards in the same two spaces over and over again. You probably need to remember where you've been and not backtrack within the same route, but make sure this state is temporary so that you can correctly backtrack to a previous junction and try a different direction. In fact it looks like you're trying to do that, except you're setting the current square to 1 (OK) not 0 (blocked).

Comment: You haven't show us 'isSafe'. I assume that does a bounds check then returns if the square is != 0?

Comment: @rup Yes exactly, 

return (x>=0 && x < n && y>=0 && y<m && array[x][y]!=0);

Comment: OK, then I think the problem is `if(isSafe(array,x,y)) { sol[x][y] = 1;` is wrong; you need to set it to 0 instead (and put it back to 1 at the end of the block, not 0) to prevent the next recursion coming back to this square. That does mean though that the path you've taken will be left in the maze as 0s, which means that the `printsolution` won't have anything to work with, so maybe you need some other value that is also rejected by isSafe. Or instead set the square to something else in the `return true` branches to show it was the taken route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking that the step hasn't been attempted before, so your code can enter infinite loops of repeated steps.

Pass the solution array to `isSafe` and check that the coordinates have not been visited before:

```
public boolean isSafe(int[][] array, int x, int y, int[][] sol) {
    return (x >= 0 && x < n && y >= 0 && y < m && array[x][y] != 0)
        && sol[x][y] == 0;
}
```